# Phpmyadmin access denied after changing to older versions of PHP/Apache on Wampserver

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Does anyone know why this is?

I have read various things about changing the httpd.conf file but

1. the information varies and is conflicting
2. what is said to be in the file is not in the same format and there are two versions of what is meant to be there i.e. `<Directory /> </Directory>` and `<Directory something else> </Directory>`

The original PHP 5.4.3/Apache 2.4.2 is working fine but I can't see enough similar points of reference to be able to copy the httpd.conf settings over into the file for Apache 2.2.2 (which I am using with PHP 5.3.1.

```
Lines 160-166:

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>

Lines 305-310:

<Directory "cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Or is it something completely different?

Comment: When you say "access is denied" what sort of error are you getting? Failed logins or a HTTP error?

Comment: Welcome on SO Simon H ! You should use 4 spaces to indent any part of code instead of trying to perform the same using `<br />` or whatever.

Comment: 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

Comment: Ok, j0k, thanks for the <br /> tip.

Comment: @SimonH Is the phpmyadmin directory just sitting in the DocumentRoot? What is DocumentRoot set to and what is the full path of the pma install directory?

Comment: It's sitting in the apps folder, which is inside the wamp folder. localhost/phpmyadmin is the address. Does that help? Not sure what you mean exactly by document root. If it helps, I am using this for a Drupal project.

Comment: @SimonH So is phpmyadmin at `c:/wamp/www/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: phpmyadmin is at c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the following lines to httpd.conf:

```
# This tells Apache where to look for phpmyadmin
Alias /phpmyadmin C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1

# This gives permission to serve the directory
<Directory C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1>
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  # This allows eveyone to access phpmyadmin, which you may not want
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Once you have made these modifications and restarted Apache, it should work.

I suspect the first line may already be present, because you are getting a 403 and not a 404.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just have to pop out but will try this asap.

Comment: Er no it didn't. The actual site works now - which it didn't earlier - but now I get:

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Anyway, don't worry because the main thing is that the site is working now in those PHP/Apache versions, which is all I wanted to check ultimately. I've been developing in PHP 5.4 but saw that my hosting server will be PHP 5.3 based, so I wanted to check that the Drupal 7 site would be ok.

Comment: @SimonH What did you try and load when you got that error? `/phpmyadmin`? Also, can you check the apache error log? A more useful error message will have been logged there.

Comment: phpmyadmin - I'd initially gone straight into the site and saw that that was fine. It was only when I again tried to access phpmyadmin from localhost that that error message was displayed.

Comment: Sorry will need to explore this some other time. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @SimonH No worries - just come back here and put another comment with an Apache error log message (if any are logged) when you have the time to look at it.

Comment: As requested here are the last lines in the Apache log. FYI, I now have my site up and running, so this is no longer an ongoing concern for me. But I thought you'd appreciate seeing that it was my cack-handed interpretation of your solution, rather than your solution that was at fault ;-)

Comment: [Fri Jul 27 17:51:02 2012] [notice] Child 5412: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Jul 27 17:51:02 2012] [notice] Child 5412: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Fri Jul 27 17:51:02 2012] [notice] Child 5412: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Jul 27 17:51:22 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/, referer: http://localhost/
[Fri Jul 27 17:51:22 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico

Comment: [Fri Jul 27 17:47:45 2012] [notice] Server built: Apr 29 2006 18:32:31
[Fri Jul 27 17:47:45 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5600
[Fri Jul 27 17:47:45 2012] [warn] The Alias directive in C:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf at line 1 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Fri Jul 27 17:47:45 2012] [warn] The Alias directive in C:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf at line 1 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.